# How to install aircrack-ng latest version

Tags: 16.04, aircrack-ng

How to install aircrack-ng latest version from terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 11):

Since you are on the 16.04, this version already comes (As of the 13th of August 2016) with the latest version of aircrack-ng. So the only needed way would be a simple:

```
sudo apt install aircrack-ng
```

The version right now is `1.2-0~beta3-4` which corresponds to the latest one on the official Aircrack page.

Answer (score 3):

The one in the repository is already the latest version for Ubuntu 16.04.

Do `apt-cache policy aircrack-ng` to check the available version. The output should be something similar to:

```
aircrack-ng:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.2-0~beta3-4
  Version table:
     1:1.2-0~beta3-4 500
```

Now, from [Aircrack-ng website](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=downloads) the link for `Debian` packages redirects to a [develper page](https://qa.debian.org/developer.php?packages=aircrack-ng) and a [ftp page](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/aircrack-ng/) where the package version is the same as the one received from the above command.

So, to install the latest package just do:

```
sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Download from https://www.aircrack-ng.org/ latest version and unpack.
2. Open unpacked folder in terminal.
3. run `sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libnl-3-dev libnl-genl-3-dev libssl-dev ethtool shtool rfkill zlib1g-dev libpcap-dev libsqlite3-dev libpcre3-dev libhwloc-dev libcmocka-dev hostapd wpasupplicant tcpdump screen iw usbutils`
4. run `autoreconf -i`
5. run `./configure`
6. run `make`
7. run `make install`

Done!